# Typescript compile errors after upgrading react native project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, npm

I'm trying to upgrade a react native project from 0.63.3 to 0.67.0, and I'm getting too many errors when I try to run `npm run tsc`. and It seems like the typescript packages are not compatible with their original packages.

package.json dependencies

```
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.67.0",
```

package.json devDependencies

```
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
        "@types/jest": "26.0.15",
        "@types/lodash": "4.14.134",
        "@types/node": "16.11.7",
        "@types/react": "*",
        "@types/react-native": "0.63.27",
        "@types/react-native-permissions": "^2.0.0",
        "@types/react-native-push-notification": "5.0.0",
        "@types/rtree": "1.4.27",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.2",
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "lib": [
            "es6"
        ],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "outDir": "artifacts",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "types": [
            "rtree"
        ],
        "typeRoots": [
            "private_types",
            "node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to show the errors together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed this by adding this line to resolutions in package.json `"@types/react": "17.0.48",`